# How to securely set dynamic HTML content with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script, security

### Description

I have implemented a frontend script that gets a few text options from the server via `wp_add_inline_script`.

When the user does an action the content should dynamically change to one of the given texts.
I want to allow HTML in these texts.

Currently, I'm escaping the texts with `wp_kses_post` before setting them in `wp_add_inline_script`.
Then in the frontend I use `element.innerHTML` to overwrite the contents of some elements.

### Questions

1. Is this considered insecure because another script could overwrite the values set via `wp_add_inline_script` to something malicious?
2. Is there a better (more secure) alternative?

### Example code

Somewhere in the backend:

```php
// These can be configured by an admin.
$texts = array(
    'loading' => '<p><i>Please wait...</i></p>',
    'error'   => '<p>Something went wrong...</p>',
    'success' => '<p><b>It worked! This is your %value%!</b></p>',
);
$json = wp_json_encode( $texts );
wp_add_inline_script( SCRIPT_HANDLE, "const myPluginTexts = $json", 'before' );
wp_enqueue_script( SCRIPT_HANDLE );
```

Somewhere in the frontend:

```js
element.innerHTML = myPluginTexts.loading;
// Do something resulting in `success` and `value` being set.
if ( success ) {
    element.innerHTML = myPluginTexts.success.replace('%value%', value);
} else {
    element.innerHTML = myPluginTexts.error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `wp_kses_post` to escape the texts before setting them in `wp_add_inline_script` is a good approach to prevent malicious content from being added to the page. This will ensure that the text is properly sanitized and only contains allowed HTML tags and attributes.

If you want to allow certain HTML tags and attributes, you can use `wp_kses` instead of `wp_kses_post` and pass an array of allowed tags and attributes as a second argument.

Using `element.innerHTML` to set the contents of the elements is generally safe, as long as the content being set has been properly sanitized. In this case, since you are using `wp_kses_post` (or `wp_kses` with an appropriate set of allowed tags and attributes) to sanitize the text, it should be safe to use `element.innerHTML`.